# Numerical computation of the radius of convergence

Tags: numerical-methods, power-series

Suppose I have a power series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n $$
and I'm interested in the numerical value of the radius of convergence $R$. The Cauchy-Hadamard theorem suggests that
$$\frac{1}{R} \approx \sqrt[N]{|a_N|} $$ 
if $N$ is large. Moreover, if none of the coefficients are zero (at least from some point) then another way to approximate $R$ is by the ratio test approach by
$$\frac{1}{R} \approx \left| \frac{a_{N+1}}{a_N} \right| $$
My question is as follows: both methods suggested here are based on the limiting results which give $1/R$ exactly. However, is there a more sophisticated way to find the radius of convergence numerically (preferably with arbitrary precision)?

If not, is it known which one of the two converges faster to $1/R$ in general? For example, the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n $$
has $R=1$, and gives rise to two approximations
$$\sqrt[N]{N}, \frac{N+1}{N}. $$
Since it can be shown that (eventually)
$$1 \leq \frac{N+1}{N} \leq \sqrt[N]{N} $$
one would prefer the ratio approach in this case.

**EDIT:**
Regarding the coefficients, we may assume there's a recursive formula for them, which originates from substitution of the power series ansatz in an ODE.

Comment: In what form are the coefficients provided? There is an infinity of coefficients, but any input to an algorithm has to be finite.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks, I've addressed your point.

Comment: Asking for the radius of convergence of $f(x)$ is the same as asking for the closest complex roots of $1/f(x)$, which is also a power series whose coefficients can be computed from those of $f$. Thus you might also explore root finding or root bounding methods for power series. -- As you do not have the coefficients in an all-at-once fashion, you can not really control the behavior at infinity. You can however employ convergence accelerating methods like Atkins or Wynns epsilon method.